# Why is set.remove so slow here?

Tags: python, performance, set, python-internals

(Extracted from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76122610/12671057).) Removing this set's 200,000 elements one by one like this takes 30 seconds ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3A4sVbBWKU0s0ihLz0lM1jAxAQFOTqzwjMydVodiKSwEI0vKLFCoUMvNgfBAo1itKzc0vS9Wo0ISLJRWlJmZDDIaaD7MHAA)):

```py
s = set(range(200000))
while s:
    for x in s:
        s.remove(x)
        break
```

Why is that so slow? Removing a set element is supposed to be fast.

Comment: How much slower is it than just looping through the set without doing anything?

Comment: what's strange to me is that this isn't raising an error on the first iteration for trying to change the size of a set while iterating

Comment: @Barmar significantly slower.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well there's the `break`, so no continued iteration.

Comment: You don't need the `while` loop. Just `for x in s: s.remove(x)`

Comment: @KellyBundy so the error isn't raised until the next `__next__` or something?

Comment: @Barmar that will raise an error though

Comment: @Barmar About 1000x slower. Pure iteration takes ~6 ms. [Demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY87DsJADET7PYXL3SIIOoSUs6AFeckK9iPbIeEsNGngTrkN-RAKYMrxvLHm_sw3qVLsukctrtj2vaMUQHxA8CEnEshIbn9MdRQksDzdlGIogVE02XhCvVmPMmbwxQ5MOaW0US4RtOAj8E7BoGyZVSYfRc8JKGBCftGm8hdcuO-eUbwiDOmKujUf70Boz_8fzAPfO5e9Lw).

Comment: I think the slowness is from `for x in s:`. If you do `for i in range(100000): s.remove(i)` it's fast.

Comment: @Barmar The code structure including the `while` comes from that other question and is crucial.

Comment: So the expense is from creating 100,000 set iterators. But `for _ in range(100000): i = iter(s)` doesn't take any time, either. Not sure where the cost really is.

Comment: How much work does the garbage collector have to do from disposing the iterator after every broken loop?

Comment: @slothrop Not much, that's not it.

Comment: so when the set iterator advances, it goes through the hashtable checking each position until it finds an occupied one. With this "broken loop" style, it probably does quite a lot of work repeatedly checking and skipping the same empty positions on each new for-loop? https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0b7fd8ffc5df187edf8b5d926cee359924462df5/Objects/setobject.c#L815

Comment: @slothrop Please remember the comment field's instruction *"Avoid answering questions in comments"* (some previous comments were borderline, but at least they were wrong).

Comment: @slothrop to clarify, the number of empty positions it has to iterate over *increases* each time, hence the quadratic time behavior. See my answer for my proposal of why this behavior occurs.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga *"so the error isn't raised until the next `__next__` or something?"* - Yes, it's the iterator's `__next__` method that *would* complain about the change during iteration. It's just not called again (for the same iterator), thanks to the break.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is happening because you are removing the *first* element in the set every time. This creates a set which is increasingly empty one each iteration, so each time you create a new iterator and call `__next__`, it has to search further and further away.

So, here is the [source code for the iterator `__next__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0b7fd8ffc5df187edf8b5d926cee359924462df5/Objects/setobject.c#L793)

It has to find the next entry like this:

```
while (i <= mask && (entry[i].key == NULL || entry[i].key == dummy))
    i++;
```

The the iterator `__next__` works by finding the *first* non-empty, non-dummy value:

So, say we have something like:

```
entries = [null, 1, null, 2, null, 3, null, 4,  null, 5]
```

Then on each iteration of the `while` loop, you get:

```
entries = [null, 1, null, 2, null, 3, null, 4,  null, 5]
entries = [null, DUMMY, null, 2, null, 3, null, 4,  null, 5]
entries = [null, DUMMY, null, DUMMY, null, 3, null, 4,  null, 5]
entries = [null, DUMMY, null, DUMMY, null, DUMMY, null, 4,  null, 5]
```

So each time, the iterator has to search further and further away from the beginning of the entires, since each iteration of the while loop removes the *first one*. Hence, the quadratic time behavior.

Comment: Yep, that's it (well, together with iteration starting at index 0, which is set in the iterator creation. Maybe it could use the set's "finger" like `pop` does (which makes it fast), didn't really look into that).

Comment: Such a [Shlemiel](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).

Comment: At least on CPython (tested Py3.10.8), ``sys.getsizeof`` also clearly shows the set does not shrink after removing items. (PyPy doesn't offer `getsizeof` but also does not seem to suffer from the slowdown problem.)

Comment: @KellyBundy yeah, I'm not really sure how the finger works exactly, so not sure why they don't use it.

Comment: Even it it could be used, I suspect they'd say "You should use `pop` instead anyway".

Comment: The finger is just an index, stored in the set's metadata. Exclusively used by pop. After popping a value it stores the *next* position as the finger so that the next pop can start searching from there instead of from index 0.  Repeated pops are a common enough use case that it's worth avoiding the slowness demonstrated here.